# "In" or "On" when talking about the "last couple of days of someone's career"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

As far as I understand in English you use "**on**", when talking about days, but is it still correct to use "**on**" in a sentences like the below one?

> He has been running for four hours per day on average for 60 days in a row, but only 1 hour 20 minutes per day **on** the last 15 days of his career as a marathon runner.

or should we use "**in**" here?

> He has been running for four hours per day on average for 60 days in a row, but only 1 hour 20 minutes per day **in** the last 15 days of his career as a marathon runner.

Which one is grammatically correct? Do we still use "on" here? The second sentence looks better to me, but I'm not so good at grammar. Can someone help me here with the explanation?

Comment: It's _on_ a particular day, but _in_ or _during_ a period of several days.

Comment: So just to clarify, it's **in** since it's a period of 15 days?

Comment: That's how I would say it. However, it would be possible to understand the first version as meaning 'on [each of] the last 15 days'.